# How to organize files properly in Python projects

Tags: python

I am having some difficulty with projects in Python. This is with reference to [Qn 48](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) of [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

The line of the tester `lexicon_tests.py` that's throwing up a problem:

```
from ex48 import lexicon
```

The error I am seeing is:

```
ImportError: no module named ex48
```

I wonder if this is because I haven't organized my files properly within the projects folder: I have a folder named `ex48`, subfolders of which include `tests` and `lexicon`. Within `lexicon`, I have the file `lexicon.py`. Within `tests`, I have the file `lexicon_tests.py`

Is there an error in the above organization?

EDIT: Posting the code here -

In /ex48, I have setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'description': 'My Project',
    'author': 'MyName',
    'url': 'URL to get it at.',
    'download_url': 'Where to download it.',
    'author_email': 'My email.',
    'version': '0.1',
    'install_requires': ['nose'],
    'packages': ['ex48'],
    'scripts': [],
    'name': 'projectname'
}

setup(**config)
```

in /ex48/lexicon, I have lexicon.py

```
class lexicon:
    @staticmethod

    def scan(string):   

        direction = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'down', 'up', 'left',          'right', 'back']
        verbs = ['go','stop','kill','eat']
        stop = ['the','in', 'of', 'from', 'at','it']
        nouns = ['door', 'bear', 'princess', 'cabinet']

        words = string.split()

        result = []
        for word in words:
                if word in direction:
                result.append(('direction',word))
```

and so on . .  . with `return result` at the end. All the environment variables have been correctly added. The error I see is `ImportError` with the name lexicon.

Comment: Learn python the hard way: `help('import')`. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this

```
from ex48 import lexicon
result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
```

to work, you should put `lexicon.py` in the folder `ex48`, and `lexicon.py` should contain a `scan` function at module level, not as a class method.

With your current code, where you have a class `lexicon` in module `lexicon` in package `lexicon`, the import statement would have to look like

```
from ex48.lexicon.lexicon import lexicon
```

Comment: @melony Did you try it after following the advice of the other answers?

Comment: Yes - but I get a new error now - indicated this as part of the comments to the previous answer.

Comment: Worked! Finally understood my mistake -- Super, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Check if a file *`__init__.py`* exists in the ex48 folder. It is required to create a package and can be empty.

Comment: If `lexicon` is a subfolder, it must have a init file too.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that ex48 isn't in your python import search path. You can check that by doing:

```
    import sys
    sys.path
```

**EDIT**

Here is a step by step tutorial of adding paths to python's import search path: [Set up Windows Python Path system environment variable](http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/setting-up-windows-python-path-system-variable.php). I'm guessing you didn't add them properly if they still don't appear in `sys.path` and until they do that import has no reason to work.

**EDIT**

Now after your new errors. When you do `from ex48 import lexicon` one of the following should be true in order for that to work:

1. A folder named `lexicon` exists in the folder `ex48`, and **both** `ex48` and `lexicon` have an `__init__.py`
2. `lexicon.py` is located directly in `ex48` and also a `__init__.py` is in `ex48`.

**EDIT**

The error you say you get from your last comment are caused by bad identation. The code you posted above needs and extra identation level for each line below `def scan(string):`

Comment: You can also modify that same import search path on windows via `system environment variables` and clicking the 'advanced' button, or with GNU stuff at `~/.bashrc` (or sometimes `.bash_profile`).

Comment: Yep - The path of C:/Python27/Projects and C:/Python27/Projects/ex48 was not included. I added this path to the system environment variables on Windows ... but I still get the same error. Moreover, If I try sys.path, the new path I included does not seem to show up! Don't understand this.

Comment: Did you start a new session/terminal. From what I know system variables changes are not visible until a new command prompt is opened.

Comment: Yes - I did start a new session.

Comment: Oh and better to define a new variable named PYTHONPATH (if it doesn't exist yet) and add them there. Python will look for default in local directory, PYTHONPATH variable, then site-packages and rest of system specific places(not sure where exactly you added those paths).

Comment: Ok that worked -- but i have a new error, Import Error: cannot import name lexicon

Comment: Thanks - Now I have followed your latest Edit (I have a folder named lexicon inside the folder ex48, and both ex48 and lexicon have a __init.py__), but I get  6 attribute errors: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scan', from lexicon_tests.py

Comment: Sorry - i posted the code here with poor indentation. The code i am running is indented in the correct manner..

Comment: Finally understood my mistake - i had to use scan as a function at module level, not within a class (pls see answer to Janne).Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in your ex48 project, you'll see there's a setup.py file.  In there, you'll see the line:

```
'packages': ['NAME'],
```

What you'll want to do is change NAME to your folder name (ex48) so it looks like this:

```
'packages': ['ex48'],
```

Make sure in the ex48 folder, you have lexicon.py with a scan function defined.  No need for a new class.

Once that's been edited nosetests should run properly with:

```
from ex48 import lexicon
```

Comment: His `setup.py` already has the correct `packages` line, doesn't it?